# Expandable datatables in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, datatables

So am trying to populate an expandable data table with the data of the child and parent from different queries as shown below in my controller.

```
public function data()
{

    $users = User::get(['first_name']);

    return Datatables::of($users)
                    ->make(true);

    $roles = Campaign::get(['campaign_name']);

    return Datatables::of($roles)
                    ->make(true);
}
```

The thing is with the ajax request i can only get one result, that is the one for the parent, but yet ad like to get both results so that on clicking the expand button one can be able to view more details.
here is my js code

```
function format(d) {


return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
'<tr>' +
'<td>Campaign Name:</td>' +
'<td>' + d.campaign_name + '</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
'<td>Company:</td>' +
'<td>' + d.company + '</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
'<td>Extra info:</td>' +
'<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'</table>';
}
$(document).ready(function() {



var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "{{ route('inventory.data') }}",
    "columns": [{
      "className": 'details-control',
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": ''
    }, {
      "data": "first_name"
    } {
      "data": "campaign_name"
    }],
    "order": [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
});
```

Please help out

Comment: When you use return it will end the execution of that method there and then so after your first `return` nothing else if going to happen with the method.

Comment: @Ross Wilson so what should i use? because for the second query its gonna return more than one row of data

Comment: How do `User` and `Campaign` relate to each other?

Comment: @Ross Wilson user has a foreign key on campaign..but here is the thing, so I wanted to list the campaigns the user is doing..